# Detect if the mouse is clicked outside GroupBox

Tags: qt, qgroupbox

I am looking for an event if the mouse is clicked outside of the groupBox in Qt. I tried FocusOutEvent but was not able to get the event:

```
ui.groupBox->installEventFilter(this); 

void myClass::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event) { ui.groupBox->hide(); }
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that `focusOutEvent` has nothing to do with mouse clicks.

Comment: You want to detect clicks outside a GroupBox, but inside what. Your whole application? Can you make your situation more concrete, a [mcve] if possible.

Comment: When I press a toolbox I get a groupbox Popup and I want to close the groupbox when I clicked outside of it.

Comment: In that case, `focusOutEvent` may be appropriate, but there are other possibilities to loose focus besides clicking outside the window. Is this ok for you. Please provide your essential code.

Comment: ui.groupBox->installEventFilter(this);                                                                                                           void myClass::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event)
{
 ui.groupBox->hide();
} I tried this!

Answer (score 0):

You have the following options:

1. Subclass `QGroupBox` and override `mousePressEvent()`
2. Install an event filter on that group box and catch QMouseEvents
3. If you want to catch only right mouse clicks (context menu), implement a custom context menu handler.

Comment: Does this solve the problem of detecting clicks _outside_ the `QGroupBox`?

Comment: In the constructor of the main class I used                            
 ui.groupBox_8->installEventFilter(this);                                                            
void myClass::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
 QMessageBox::information(this, "mouse", "clicked");
}                                                                                                                     I tried this but it is not working! Could you share a code snippet so that I can understand well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the events of the monitored object are not forwarded to the native event handlers of the filter object such as `focusOutEvent`, but to a special virtual event function, i.e. [`eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) as documented in [`installEventFilter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#installEventFilter). So, your event handler should look like this:

```
bool myClass::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (obj == ui.groupBox && event->type () == QEvent::FocusOut)
        ui.groupBox->hide(); 
    return false;
}
```

Comment: ui.groupBox->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint|Qt::Popup);  ui.groupBox->installEventFilter(this);                                                              bool myClass::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
 if (obj == ui.groupBox && event->type() == QEvent::FocusOut)
 {
  ui.groupBox->hide();
  
 }

 return false;
} I am able to get the object but not the FocusOut Event.

Comment: The reason probably is that it never has focus. You may assign focus manually by calling `setFocus`.