# Search string in QTextEdit on typing

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QTextEdit` on the screen, with text in it. I want to be able to type a search string, and have the cursor move to the next occurrence of that string in the `QTextEdit` - but without my typing actually going into the text edit. If the `QTextEdit` has focus, the stuff I type goes into it, and if it doesn't have focus then there is no cursor. Can anyone help please?

Comment: You can use QCompleter to provide auto completions in any Qt widget, such as QLineEdit and QComboBox

Comment: The search is no problem - it's working fine. I just need to be able to show the TextEdit cursor without what I type on the keyboard going into the text.

Comment: Show cursor or change position of cursor?

Comment: I need to do both. Trouble is that if the cursor is showing, anything I type gets entered into the text. I need to be able to type without it becoming part of the text in the TextEdit.

Comment: Clarify more what you want, what you tried? codes or photos of desired result. by defaults a text cursor is showing when typing.</br> your above message sounds strange to me.

Comment: I would have thought I'd explained it quite clearly. I want to type a search string - without that search string showing anywhere - and I want the cursor in the TextEdit to go to the next occurrence of that string in the text on the screen, if it finds one. As I said, the search is working fine, and qDebug is reporting the position in the displayed text of that next occurrence. All I need is to be able to put the cursor there.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities:

1. Reimplement [`QTextEdit::keyPressEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qplaintextedit.html#keyPressEvent) to capture the entered text without displaying it. As an alternative, you can use an [event filter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters), which has the advantage that you do not have to subclass `QTextEdit`.

or

2. Create a (small) search box widget (eg. `QLineEdit` on top of your `QTextEdit`), which you give focus instead of your main `QTextEdit`. In this way, the current search string is fed back to the user.

*Note that I prefer the second option, because of the visual feedback.*

Comment: Aha. Right. Thank you :) Probably 1. I tried 2. but it didn't do what I wanted.

Comment: I've read the event filter docs, but it's so complicated - and I'm a real noob with this. I just don't understand it. Any suggestions on how I could set up such a filter?

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394284/detect-if-the-mouse-is-clicked-outside-groupbox/44408622#44408622) or your favorite search engine may be helpful. Basically, you should call `textEdit->installEventFilter(myClass)` And implement `MyClass::eventFilter` to process the captured events.